# to find sum of primes up to 2 million

Tags: java, arrays, primes

I am trying to find the sum of all prime numbers <=2 million so i used sieve of Eratosthenes TO mark all prime numbers .As i declared the boolean array of size 2 million ,i got this error

```
             "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2000000
```

Since the sum can be two large so i used long instead of sum .here is the code in java

```
public class Summationofprimes {
    static  long[] isprime=new long[2000000];

     static void sieve(){
         Arrays.fill(isprime, 0);//all marked false
         isprime[1]=1;isprime[0]=1;
         for(int i=2;i*i<=2000000;i++){
             if(isprime[i]==0){
                // print(i);
                // sum+=i;
                //print(sum);
                 for(int j = i * i; j <= 2000000 ;j += i){
                     isprime[j]=1;// all multiples marked true 
                 }
             }
         }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sieve();
        long sum=0;
        System.out.println("sum is :");
        for(int i=2;i<=2000000;i++){
            if(isprime[i]==0){
                sum+=i;


        }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

How do i fix this issue in code ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for(int j = i; ...` in your inner loop?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
static  long[] isprime=new long[2000001];
```

Now it has range from 0 to 2000000

Comment: it worked,i had done it wrong earlier

Comment: Since we already know that 2000000 is not a prime, another and slightly nicer solution would be to use `< 2000000` rather than `<= 2000000`.